# Scala wrong type inference

Tags: scala, type-inference

```
val finalRDD = joinedRDD.map(x => {
          val d1 = x._2._1
          val d2 = x._2._2
          (x._1, d1 + d2)
        })
```

In the above code, `joinedRDD` has type `RDD[(Row, (Double, Double))]` (according to IntelliJ) while Scala compiler says `d1` & `d2` are `AnyVal`. 
For time being, I cast `d1` & `d2` as `Double` using `asInstanceOf` but next time it says

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Double

Is it Scala compiler issue or IntelliJ issue which shows me wrong inferred types. Any insights?

Comment: Unrelated to the type inference problem, but I always prefer pattern matching to the `._1`, `._2`  syntax on tuples. I'd do this instead: `val (_, (d1, d2)) = x`. If you switch to `mapValues`, as per kaktusito's suggestion, then you won't need the outer tuple at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems good to me :-S
Type inference is far from omniscient. Sometimes you need to specify the types explicitly. In my experience, this is especially true when the result type can be anything. Some things to try:

1. My preferred option since you are not touching the key: `joinedRDD.mapValues(x => x._1 + x._2)`
2. Add some type information: `val d1: Double = x._2._1`. With some luck, at least the compiler might be more explicit.
3. Define your function separately, assigning types to the parameters, and use if inside: `map(myFunc)`

Also, I've seen some differences between IntelliJ Scala Plugin and the actual Scala compiler. Given the errors you are getting and the fact that AnyVal is the common parent class for both Int and Double, there is a good chance you don't have doubles to begin with (and the compiler is trying to find a shared parent). Do double check that you are getting the type you mention by putting it explicitly. It is very possible that your type confusion occurs before this line.

Good luck!

Comment: Note: my first option is rather Spark-specific, but seems the best match to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Advice about `mapValues` was good, however what actually helped me was giving explicit type information. (I should have tried it before asking :( ).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried in IntelliJ IDEA 14 and the type inference is correct, recognizing d1 and d2 as `Double` (this was expected). Nonetheless, I usually avoid the type-aware highlighting feature of IDEA since many times it goes crazy and reports fake results.

As a side note, since you are not changing the key of your RDD, consider using `mapValues` instead of `map` (this provides clarity, as well as performance since it would take advantage of the partitioner of the input RDD and reuse it in the output RDD).